# How can I make a CSS grid unresponsive to a changing element inside of it?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a basic grid like this. How can I make it unresponsive to a changing element inside of it? Example: If I put an element like a button into it and the text changes (for example from "not ready" to "ready"), the size of the whole container should stay the same. But I can't really find anything how to achieve this. Or am I using the wrong technology?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
  <div class="three"></div>
</div>

<style>
  .container {
    display: grid; 
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 0.7fr 1.3fr; 
    grid-template-rows: 0.2fr 0.6fr 1.6fr; 
    gap: 0px 0px; 
    grid-template-areas: 
      "header header header"
      "one one two"
      "one one three"; 
  }
  .header { grid-area: header; }
  .one { grid-area: one; }
  .two { grid-area: two; }
  .three { grid-area: three; }
</style>
```

Comment: did you try redefine `grid-template-areas` in your media query?

Comment: maybe I should have phrased my question better. I'm more interested into how I can make it not influenced by elements inside it. If I put an element like a button into it and the text changes (for example from "not ready" to "ready"), the size of the whole container should stay the same, but I don't really know how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work with percentages instead of flexible lengths `fr` on the columns e.g. `grid-template-columns: 30% 30% 40%;`

### Try the following snippet

```css
.container {
  display: grid; 
  grid-template-columns: 30% 30% 40%; 
  grid-template-rows: 0.2fr 0.6fr 1.6fr; 
  gap: 0px 0px; 
  height:100vh;
  border:1px solid black;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "header header header"
    "one one two"
    "one one three"; 
}
.header { grid-area: header; border:1px solid blue; }
.one { grid-area: one; border:1px solid blue;}
.two { grid-area: two; border:1px solid blue;}
.three { grid-area: three; border:1px solid blue;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
  <div class="three"><button>way waaay more than ready</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much! I was thinking way to complicated and searched for an extra property etc.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. Always try to find the simplest way of doing something. CSS can be really simple if you let it be. If you don't know Bootstrap check it out.